# Networkx Graph Attribute showing None

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I created a networkx graph with node 1 with a certain attribute, x by assigning:

```
graph.nodes[1]['attr'] = x
```

However when I printed it out I got something like this:
print(graph.nodes[1]['attr'])

None

x

Does anyone know why None appears before x?

Comment: Seems like there is not enough code here to reproduce this behavior.  Could you post more of the code that gives this result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are planning to use 'attr' in your graph but you can accomplish what you asked for like this:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
x = 'something'
G.nodes[1]['attr'] = x
print(G.nodes[1]['attr']) 

#something
```